# How to handle floating point numbers in Mac OS X awk?

Tags: macos, awk

On Mac OS X 10.9 the following line

```
echo "1.2 2.3" | awk '{print $1 + $2}'
```

prints this result

```
3
```

This is with the system version of awk. Obviously, I would like it to print

```
3.5
```

just as I'm used to from e.g. `gawk` (installed with Homebrew), or from `mawk` on my Debian box. Any ideas how I can do that? I have not found out by reading the (very sparse) man page, nor by googling.

Comment: Works for me on default OS X install and awk --version reporting "awk version 20070501"

Comment: Which version of Mac OS X? On 10.9 Mavericks with a regular (`en_US.UTF-8`) locale settings, I get 3.5.  Do you by any chance use a locale where `,` is the decimal point marker?

Comment: You are right @JonathanLeffler, I'm a victim of my locale :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out, sorry for bothering everyone. The reason seems to be my locale, which is set to `de_CH.UTF-8` via the `LANG` env var.

When I set `LANG` to `en_US.UTF-8` the calculation is correct. Interestingly, gawk is not affected by LANG...

Comment: awk is working as expected. By default `gawk` is not following the standard behavior but will behave like `awk` should you have used the `--posix` option.